# How to disable windows minimization to the "Activities button" on Gnome?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, docky

I'm using oneiric with gnome shell and Docky. The windows are minimizes to the "Activities" overview on the panel. How can I get the minimize effect for docky instead to the Activities?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to do the same but with frippery bottom panel, instead of the dock. The concept is the same though. I think you can edit this file:

/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/windowManager.js

**I tried pinpointing the effect but the only thing I find here is this:**

```
/* scale window down to 0x0.
     * maybe TODO: get icon geometry passed through and move the window towards it?
     */
    this._minimizing.push(actor);

    let primary = Main.layoutManager.primaryMonitor;
    let xDest = primary.x;
    if (Clutter.get_default_text_direction() == Clutter.TextDirection.RTL)
        xDest += primary.width;

    Tweener.addTween(actor,
                     { scale_x: 0.0,
                       scale_y: 0.0,
                       x: xDest,
                       y: 0,
                       time: WINDOW_ANIMATION_TIME,
                       transition: 'easeOutQuad',
                       onComplete: this._minimizeWindowDone,
                       onCompleteScope: this,
                       onCompleteParams: [shellwm, actor],
                       onOverwrite: this._minimizeWindowOverwritten,
                       onOverwriteScope: this,
                       onOverwriteParams: [shellwm, actor]
                     });
},
```

If there were any other transitions, maybe it would be possible to substitute it. I could even settle for a fadeout transition. I just don't know where these variables are specified. I think the important lines are **x: xDest,** , **y: 0,** and **transition: 'easeOutQuad',**

If there's anybody willing to add to this or correct it, please help.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to resurrect such an old thread but I'm looking to write some custom animations for Gnome Shell and this is just about the only thread I can find that was vaguely helpful.

Just in case it helps anyone else, here's what I've worked out so far:

```
// push the current actor onto the 
// minimising stack / queue / list / 
// whatever it is

this._minimizing.push(actor);

// get the main monitor

let primary = Main.layoutManager.primaryMonitor;

// calculate the destination for the x 
// coordinate (0,0 is top left so this 
// is presumably 0 for single monitor set ups)

let xDest = primary.x;

// if Clutter is configured to use 
// right-to-left text, then the 
// activities button is on the 
// right hand side, so add the 
// monitor width to xDest

if (Clutter.get_default_text_direction() == Clutter.TextDirection.RTL)
    xDest += primary.width;

// add the animation to the window

Tweener.addTween(actor,
                 { 

                   // shrink the height and width down to 0

                   scale_x: 0.0,
                   scale_y: 0.0,

                   // move to the calculated destination
                   // (most likely top-left i.e. 0,0)

                   x: xDest,
                   y: 0,

                   // take the correct amount of time

                   time: WINDOW_ANIMATION_TIME,

                   // set the type of curve to use
                   // during the animation

                   transition: 'easeOutQuad',

                   // set up some events to trigger 
                   // when were done

                   onComplete: this._minimizeWindowDone,
                   onCompleteScope: this,
                   onCompleteParams: [shellwm, actor],
                   onOverwrite: this._minimizeWindowOverwritten,
                   onOverwriteScope: this,
                   onOverwriteParams: [shellwm, actor]
                 });
```

So long story short if you have your dock at the bottom, you could easily make the animation go to the middle of it by doing:

x: primary.x + (primary.width / 2)

y: primary.height

Not perfect but it's a start...

Answer (score 1):

The only way to change this (currently) without changing the source code, would be to write an extension which changes the properties of the minimize animation so that it targets the dock.

Comment: See @agus.winger 's answer, he points to an existing extension.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the GNOME extenstion [Disable Window Animations](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/119/disable-window-animations/):

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.